# If hitTestObject = true return current position on screen?

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection, game-physics, flashdevelop

I'm making a 2d platform game and i'm not knowledgeable enough to know how to set up collisions with my character and platforms.

I basically want when fireboy1 hits basePlatform, fireboy1 to not be able to go any further

I have got this code so far i'm just struggling to understand what to put in the if statement itself.
I have commented the part I am unsure about.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

```
public function platformCollision():void
    {
        if (fireboy1.hitTestObject(basePlatform))
        {
            fireboy1.y = fireboy1.y = //current position on screen?
        }
    }
```

Comment: `fireboy1.y = fireboy1.y` doesn't actually do anything. You're basically setting the `y` property to the same value it's already at. What do you mean when you say "current position on screen"? If you don't want `fireboy1` to go past the `basePlatform`, you should probably do something like `fireboy1.y = basePlatform.y - fireboy1.height`. Please note that this all depends on both `fireboy1` and `basePlatform` having top-left orientation. My suggestion is to add some more code for context.

Comment: This has worked perfectly thank you!

Comment: I've added it as an answer so that you can mark it.

Comment: Have you tried using game frameworks like [Flixel](http://flixel.org/), [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) to mention two first results from search engine? That way you will have to built in all the base functionality and you can focus on the game. Why re-invent the wheel?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want `fireboy1` to go past the `basePlatform`, you should probably do something like:

`fireboy1.y = basePlatform.y - fireboy1.height`

Please note that this all depends on both fireboy1 and basePlatform having top-left orientation.

Answer (score 0):

no need for a hitTestObject....
lets assume that the regstration point for fireboy and the base platform are in its centre:

```
public function loop(e:Event){
 if(fireboy1.y + fireboy1.height > basePlatform.y - basePlatform.height){
  fireboy1.y = basePlatform.y - fireboy1.height;
 } 
}
```